# Mapping between two arrays - Mongodb

Tags: mongodb

```
    "receiver_name": ["Fan Two", "Mike Jones" ], 
    "receiver_role": [ "user", "performer"]
```

how to create it `{Fan Two:user, mike jones:performer}`  by using mongodb query?

Comment: Welcome to SO, can you explain your question with more details.

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for `$zip`

[play](https://mongoplayground.net/p/vOcoZrfKJro)

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      "output": {
        "$zip": {
          "inputs": [
            "$receiver_name",
            "$receiver_role"
          ],
          
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```